# Обработка строки и поиск значения в ней

Tags: python, поиск, строки

Есть текст такого формата в формате строки

```
Оборот:  473 051  (  333 337  )
Основа:  429 961  (  223 333  )
Аксы:  43 090  (  100 000  )
Услуги:  0  (  4  )
Сервис:  0  (  10 000  )
CPU:  1  (  1  )
iPad:  1  (  1  )
iPhone:  2  (  2  )
Watch:  0  (  1  )
SIM:  0    1  
Средний чек:  43 005  (  37 000  )
Штуки в чеке:  1,73  (  1,6  )
Доля аксов:  9,1%  (  17%  )
Конвертация:  4,1%  (  12%  )
Трафик  268      
СБП  91,34  (  30%  )
```

Нужен примерно следующий функционал: при запросе например 'Основа' вытащить 429 961 и (  223 333  ) и вычислить процент
Итог примерно такой Основа : 192%
На данный момент есть код который с этим справляется, но через кучу костылей и далеко не самый изящный)))

Comment: Рекоммендую изучить регулярные выражения, они помогут разбить любую строку из указанных вами на нужное число групп, с каждой из которых можно работать в отдельности.
[1]: https://habr.com/ru/post/349860/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
txt = """Оборот:  473 051  (  333 337  )
Основа:  429 961  (  223 333  )
Аксы:  43 090  (  100 000  )
Услуги:  0  (  4  )
Сервис:  0  (  10 000  )
CPU:  1  (  1  )
iPad:  1  (  1  )
iPhone:  2  (  2  )
Watch:  0  (  1  )
SIM:  0    1  
Средний чек:  43 005  (  37 000  )
Штуки в чеке:  1,73  (  1,6  )
Доля аксов:  9,1%  (  17%  )
Конвертация:  4,1%  (  12%  )
Трафик  268      
СБП  91,34  (  30%  )"""

a = txt.split('\n') # Разбиение текста на строки
for el in a:
    el = el.replace(' ','') # Удалиение пробелов
    el = el.replace(',','.') # Замена запятых на точки
    s = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', el)] # Выборка чисел
    key = el[:el.find(':')] # Выборка заголовка
    try:
        print(f"{key} {s[0]/(s[1]/100)} %")
    except:
        print(f"{key} Нехватает данных")
```

Могу такое решение предложить, с построчным перебором, удалением лишних символом, и выборкой чисел при помощи регулярного выражения

Comment: s = [1.0, 73.0, 1.0, 6.0] Штуки в чеке:  1,73  (  1,6  )

Comment: @СергейШ Да, действительно. Значит надо реплейсом еще заменить запятые на точки

Comment: Всем спасибо! Отличные решения!

Comment: @АндрейПеревязко Пожалуйста :)
И не забудьте принять ответ, если он подошел

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант разбора, не идеальный, но как заготовка. Разбираю сразу в словарь и поиск уже из словаря идёт, чтобы быстро.

```
import re

text = """
Оборот:  473 051  (  333 337  )
Основа:  429 961  (  223 333  )
Аксы:  43 090  (  100 000  )
Услуги:  0  (  4  )
Сервис:  0  (  10 000  )
CPU:  1  (  1  )
iPad:  1  (  1  )
iPhone:  2  (  2  )
Watch:  0  (  1  )
SIM:  0    1  
Средний чек:  43 005  (  37 000  )
Штуки в чеке:  1,73  (  1,6  )
Доля аксов:  9,1%  (  17%  )
Конвертация:  4,1%  (  12%  )
Трафик  268      
СБП  91,34  (  30%  )"""

d = {}
re1 = re.compile(r'([^:\d]+):?([\d, ]+%?)\D*([\d, ]+%?)')
for line in text.split('\n'):
    m = re1.match(line)
    if m:
        name = m[1].strip()
        num1 = m[2].strip().replace(' ', '').replace(',','.').replace('%','')
        num2 = m[3].strip().replace(' ', '').replace(',','.').replace('%','')
        print(f'{name}:{num1}/{num2}')
        d[name.lower()] = 100*float(num1)/float(num2) if num2 else 'ошибка парсинга'
      
while True:
    name = input().lower()
    if not name:
        break
    print(d.get(name, 'не найдено'))
```